# Тип long и функция vibrate

Tags: java, android

Есть пример работы с вибрацией в телефоне:

```
    Vibrator vibr = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    // создаем паттерн (шаблон) - массив типа Long
    long[] pat = {0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 5000, 6000};
    vibr.vibrate(pat, 1); 
    //< второй параметр показывает, сколько раз повторять паттерн, -1 - не повторять
```

Почему Eclips ругается, когда указываю явно:

```
    vibr.vibrate(1000, 1);
```

И почему не вижу разницы от изменения второго параметра. Еще, может, кто знает, как изменять частоту вибрации. Знаю, что возможно, т.к. это работает в разных программах.

Немного уточню вопрос. Если pat в примере это массив из long, то какой элемент массива будет использован, ведь мы просто указываем pat, без номера элемента? Или я вообще не понимаю суть этой переменной.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pat` - это массив, а в функцию вы явно передаете `long`. Соответственно - `TypeMismatch`.
Если вместо 1000 написать `new long[]{1000}`, то это заработает.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, вы невнимательно смотрели документацию, или в том же эклипсе можно смотреть перегруженные методы и их параметры. С developer.android.com:

```
void    vibrate(long[] pattern, int repeat, AudioAttributes attributes)
Vibrate with a given pattern.

void    vibrate(long[] pattern, int repeat)
Vibrate with a given pattern.

void    vibrate(long milliseconds)
Vibrate constantly for the specified period of time.

void    vibrate(long milliseconds, AudioAttributes attributes)
Vibrate constantly for the specified period of time.
```

Как можно видеть, здесь нет метода с указанными вами во втором случае параметрами:

```
void        vibrate(long milliseconds, int repeat)
```

Вот такого то есть нету.
Массив же в первом случае выступает в качестве паттерна для вибрации, если вы хотите задать определенные промежутки между вибро и определенную продолжительность.
Опять же, из официальной документации:

> Pass in an array of ints that are the durations for which to turn on or off the vibrator in milliseconds. The first value indicates the number of milliseconds to wait before turning the vibrator on. The next value indicates the number of milliseconds for which to keep the vibrator on before turning it off. Subsequent values alternate between durations in milliseconds to turn the vibrator off or to turn the vibrator on.
>
> To cause the pattern to repeat, pass the index into the pattern array at which to
> start the repeat, or -1 to disable repeating.

[Ссылка на документацию](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html)

Comment: Благодарю за помощь. Ответ получен. Основная проблема была в том, что я не понял, что передается целый массив чисел формирующих тип вибрации, а не отдельная цифра.